# Can't access script attached to UI image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the problem that I can't access my own script, that I attached to my image object, from another script.

I can access the Image(Script) that comes when I create the image object but that's all.

Error: object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My GameManager script is the one trying to access my custom image script and this is how:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class scriptGameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image img1;

private int gmValue = 0;

    void Update () {
        gmValue = img1.GetComponent<MyImageScript>().GetValue();
    }
}
```

and the Script I attached to my Image Object is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class MyImageScript: MonoBehaviour {


    public int GetValue () {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

[image]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the UI of how you are attaching the `MyImageScript` to a `Image` and how you assign the `Image` to `img1`? (also you can delete your old comments now that you have clarified with a update)

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/u5lfvqxf5/ - here is one example, all my Image object have a script similar to this

Comment: `img1` is not null?

Comment: No, i can access the default Image(Script) and change the sprite or color for example. But i can't access the script that i added

Answer (score 1):

> I can access the Image(Script) that comes when i create the image
>   object but that's all

If I am correct, you are trying to access `MyImageScript` from the `scriptGameManager` script and the `MyImageScript` is attached to the-same GameObject `img1`(Image) is attached to.But according to the image in your comment, you do NOT have `MyImageScript` script attached to the Image.

The only script that is attached to your Image is the `ScriptCharSpot` script.

[image]

You must attach `MyImageScript` to your image within the Editor or the through code before you can use `GetComponent` on it or else, it will return `null`. At the-same time, you need to cache the `MyImageScript` script instead of calling `GetComponent` each frame.

```
public class scriptGameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Image img1;
    MyImageScript imgScript;

    private int gmValue = 0;

    void Start () {
        //Add MyImageScript to img1 
        img1.gameObject.AddComponent<MyImageScript>();
        //Get/Cache MyImageScript that is attached to img1 
        imgScript = img1.GetComponent<MyImageScript>();
    }

    void Update () {
        gmValue = imgScript.GetValue();
    }
}
```